# terminal History for one day

Tags: linux, rhel, logs

I logged in to my Linux box in morning and did lots of installations using terminal,i got lot's of errors during these installations,cleared terminal many time,solved these errors,Now i want to know all the history which i got with all those error messages which i got during installation.

I tried history and syslog ,but it doesn't give me what i am looking for.I am using RHEL6.5_64 bit

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `history` command, as you probably gathered, only shows a (sometimes imperfect) record of recent commands you executed.

The files under `/var/log` (and possibly other application-specific locations) do record much pertinent information, but do *not* record a character-by-character account of everything that appears in every system terminal, as that would be time-and-space inefficient for most operations.

## What to do next time

(Yes, I'm doing the future before the present!)

However, if you know you are going to run a command that might have a lot of output, that you might need to review later, type `script` first (be sure you have write permission for your current directory; if not, `cd ~` or somesuch first). You will see something like this:

```
Script started, file is typescript
```

After that, go ahead and run as many commands as you like, for days on end if you so choose; filesystem space permitting, you can continue indefinitely.

When you are finished, type `exit`. You will not exit your shell, but instead exit exit the `script` session. From there, you can open up the `typescript` file in your favorite text editor and get a detailed view of everything that happened. (Including control characters such as backspaces and color codes -- so sometimes it takes a bit of practice to figure it out, but in most cases, it's human readable. In the cases where it isn't, `cat typescript` will usually "replay" it, but you probably want to copy/paste smaller sections of the file before you do that!)

## What might help you this time

Since you have already executed your commands without `script` logging, you can attempt to back out your changes (or push ahead, knowing what was successfully installed, and what wasn't):

First, run this:

```
rpm -qa --last
```

That will list all currently installed packages, along with their installation dates. It will *not* list packages which did not install, obviously.

For further reading, review the `rpm` manual page and other documentation to learn how to drill down into the package information on your system.

This will give you a look at how many of your prior commands succeeded, and which ones may have failed (by process of elimination).

Armed with that extra information, it is probably easiest to run `script`, and then simply retrace your steps from the beginning, based on the higher-level goal you were trying to achieve. There is no harm in trying to install already installed packages if you make a mistake. This will almost certainly be easier than trying to look for package-specific clues in the logs and other system files.

Answer (score 2):

You have try `history` command for the last command you type, this is the most you will get.

`syslog`'s job is to monitor what happened to system (network unpluged, disk failure, user trying to log with bad credential, emergency diag from application), you will learned little, if any, from that.

There is no "automatic recording of system activities". On some system I connect to remotly I have told my `putty` to record printable output of each session, but you have to do it **before**.